# Assign roles to users Spring, Java

Tags: java, spring

So, I need to create entity "Role" and assign her to users, I don't need any authentications, registrations or whatever. All I have to do is to create role, create user and connect them 1-to-1. I've already created those entities but I cant figure out how to do this "connection".
Can anyone explain how to do something like that?

'''

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name="user_role",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private List<Role> roles;


    public List<Role> getRoles()
    {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles)
    {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

'''

'''

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserRestController(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        List<User> users = userService.retrieveUsers();
        return users;
    }

    @GetMapping("/api/users/{userId}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable(name="userId")Integer userId) {
        return userService.getUser(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/users")
    public void saveUser(User user){
        userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/api/users/{userId}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable(name="userId")Integer userId){
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
    }

///

}
```

'''

'''

```
@Service
public class RoleServiceImpl implements RoleService {

    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void RoleRepository(RoleRepository roleRepository){
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public List<Role> retrieveRoles() {
        List<Role> roles = (List<Role>) roleRepository.findAll();
        return roles;
    }

    public Role getRole(Integer roleId) {
        Optional<Role> optEmp = roleRepository.findById(roleId);
        return optEmp.get();
    }

    public void saveRole(Role role){
        roleRepository.save(role);
    }

    public void deleteRole(Integer roleId){
        roleRepository.deleteById(roleId);
    }

}
```

'''

'''

```
public interface RoleService {

    List<Role> retrieveRoles();

    Role getRole(Integer roleId);

    void saveRole(Role role);

    void deleteRole(Integer roleId);
}
```

'''

'''

```
@Data
@Entity
        @Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

'''
(there is not getters, setters because of lombok)

Comment: I dont fully understand your problem.Can you expain a little more ?

Comment: I created two entities, two separate tables - users and roles. Now I have to connect every user to one of the roles from Role - table, and show that they are connected in third table Role_Users. Something like that.

Table users: id: 1 name: xyz  |  Table Roles:id: 2  name: role1         Table users_roles: id_user: 1 id_role: 2

Comment: It seems the problem in not in spring, but in hibernate mappings. Please learn hibernate mappings using google.